How to increase line length in VSCode Jupyter output?
I'm trying to print a pandas dataframe in a cell of a Jupyter Notebook. However, for some reason, the DataFrame is truncated at some point of the line and continues above. Any clue of how to increase the number of characters printed per line in the output?
Print of notebook output
More info:

The limit of characters also affects Debug Console. When trying to print the DataFrame in Debug Console, the same behaviour occurs.

I'm using the function print() to print the DataFrame

I've tried to change pandas options without success:


pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  
pd.set_option('display.width', None)


I've tried this solution, but it didn't work.


Hello, is the version of jupyter and required libraries you use up to date? You can try changing the width of the display with pd.set_option('display.with',10000).

try adding also with the max rows settings:
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)


The option you are looking for here is display.width, which is set to 80 by default. By adding pd.set_option('display.width', None), you can disable this limit.
So, for this example DataFrame:
columns = [f'---------Column{i}' for i in range(1, 7)]
data = {col: [random.random() for _ in range(2)] for col in columns}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Before setting the pd.set_option('display.width', None):
print(df)


   ---------Column1  ---------Column2  ---------Column3  ---------Column4  \
0          0.661599          0.700977          0.252833          0.899251   
1          0.864813          0.588307          0.161888          0.051829   

   ---------Column5  ---------Column6  
0          0.271721          0.067461  
1          0.016571          0.347471  

And after:
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
print(df)


   ---------Column1  ---------Column2  ---------Column3  ---------Column4  ---------Column5  ---------Column6
0          0.165949          0.351962          0.288048          0.970479          0.461898          0.222051
1          0.128192          0.070330          0.141980          0.555047          0.965609          0.734030

